# Dar fuente de texto y tamaño a todos los jLabels de un panel

Tags: java

Tengo un formulario en **Java**, diseñado con Java Swing, el cual tengo integrado de un `JPanel` llamado "panel".

Existen algunos de los siguientes campos:

- nombre
- apellidos
- dni
- telefono
- ...

Para cambiar el tamaño de un `jLabel`, por ejemplo "nombre", logré con esta sintaxis:

```
label_nombre.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
```

Pero mi pregunta es, **¿se pueden dar a TODOS los `jLabels` de un `JPanel` en concreto la sintaxis para no ir uno a uno...?** Imaginaros que son 16... se haría costoso y poco eficiente.

Comment: Extiende JLabel, ajustando las propiedades que necesites en su constructor, y simplemente cambia la instanciación de Jlabel por tu nueva clase.

Comment: ¿Entonces debo sobreescribir la propiedad JLabel para ponerla con mis características? Es que sólo se me ocurre hacerlo uno a uno por cada jlabel que tenga.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extiende JLabel, ajustando las propiedades que necesites en su constructor, y simplemente cambia la instanciación de JLabel por tu nueva clase:

```
public class FormLabel extends JLabel{
   
   public FormLabel(String str){
      super(str);
      this.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
   }

}
```

Y en tu código actual cambia `new JLabel("...")` por `new FormLabel("...")`, así todas las `FormLabel` creadas tendrán esa fuente *"de fábrica"* sin necesidad de especificarla una por una.